# Finding a potential function.

Tags: calculus

Let $F(x,y,z) = (18xyz+8\sin(x), 9x^2z, 9x^2y)^T$. Find a function $f$ so that $F=\nabla f$, and $f(0,0,0)=0$.

So when I worked through this, the answer I got was $9x^2yz-8\cos(x)$, which is obviously wrong because $\cos(0)$ is not zero. I've worked through this problem multiple times but keep getting the same answer, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is difficult to guess what you've done wrong, since you have only showed your final result.

Comment: For lots of advice on asking a crowd-pleasing question here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959   Welcome to Mathematics Stack.

Comment: Just add 8.........

Comment: The potential is only defined up to an additive constant, just like an indefinite integral.  Just add a constant to make $f(0,0,0)=0$.  It is not at all a problem that $\cos(0)\neq 0$